# performing nested select using grails and gorm

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm, criteria, detachedcriteria

I have the following SQL query, I was wondering if I could rewrite this in GORM style with grails, possibly using criteria, where, or other programming style querying that HQL.

```
SELECT count(USERID) as Result FROM Answer
WHERE USERID IN
      (SELECT USERID FROM Answer
       WHERE USERID IN (SELECT USERID FROM Answer
             WHERE USERID IN (SELECT USERID FROM Answer WHERE QID=1 AND ATxt='30') AND 
       QID=2 AND ATxt='M') AND QID=3 AND ATxt='6') AND QID=4 AND ATxt='160'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this nested in's you could use `or`. Without knowing your domain classes, I'm assuming that you have something like:

```
class User {
}

class Question {
}

class Answer {
  static belongsTo = [user: User, question: Question]
}


def question2 = Question.findById(2)
def question3 = Question.findById(3)
def question4 = Question.findById(4)

Answer.withCriteria {
  projections {
    count('user')
  }
  or {
    and {
      eq('question', question2)
      eq('aTxt', 'M')
    }
    and {
      eq('question', question3)
      eq('aTxt', '6')
    }
    and {
      eq('question', question4)
      eq('aTxt', '160')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I use a list of questions and then iterate over them with the or{} and construct all the and{eq} parts ?

Comment: You sure can! Try it :)